# Spring boot Mockito when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

i have the following code :

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "prf")
public class AppPropertiesConfiguration {

  private String directoryPath;

    //Getter  Setter
}

@Service
public class FileService {

  private final AppPropertiesConfiguration appPropertiesConfiguration;

  public FileService(final AppPropertiesConfiguration appPropertiesConfiguration) {

    this.appPropertiesConfiguration = appPropertiesConfiguration;
  }

  public void writeFile(final byte[] byteFiletoSave, final String fileName) {

    final String directoryPath = appPropertiesConfiguration.getDirectoryPath();

    final Path path = Paths.get(directoryPath, fileName);

    try {
      Files.write(path, byteFiletoSave);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.error("Error while saving file with name {} in NAS dute to : ", fileName, e);
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my unite test :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FileServiceTest {

  @InjectMocks
  FileService fileService;

  @Mock
  AppPropertiesConfiguration appPropertiesConfigurationMock;

    @Test
    void should_write_file() {

      //Given

      final byte[] docByte = new byte[0];
      final String fileName = "justFilename.pdf";
      final String dirPath = "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3";

      when(appPropertiesConfigurationMock.getDirectoryPath()).thenReturn(dirPath);

      //When
      fileService.writeFile(docByte, fileName);

      //Then

    }
}
```

and im getting this error : `when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'`  event that i really pass a mock object to the `when` method .
do you have any idea what's exactly the issue and how to resolve it.

Comment: Why are you using a mock at all? Simply `new AppPropertiesConfiguration()` and then call `setDirectoryPath(dirPath)` on it. Why use a dynamic, heavy-weight mock object for such a simple task?